# Using inverse grep to compare two .txt files

Tags: unix, terminal, grep

I have two .txt files "test1.txt" and "test2.txt" and I want to use inverse grep (UNIX) to find out all lines in test2.txt that do not contain any of the lines in test1.txt

test1.txt contains only user names, while test2.txt contains longer strings of text.  I only want the lines in test2.txt that DO NOT contain the usernames found in test1.txt

Would it be something like?

```
grep -v test1.txt test2.txt > answer.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your were almost there just missed one option in your command (i.e -f ) 
Your Solution should be use the -f flag, see below for sample session demonstrating the same

Demo Session

```
    $ # first file
    $ cat a.txt
    xxxx yyyy
    kkkkkk
    zzzzzzzz

    $ # second file
    $ cat b.txt
    line doesnot contain any name
    This person is xxxx yyyy good
    Another line which doesnot contain any name
    Is kkkkkk a good name ?
    This name itself is sleeping ...zzzzzzzz
    I can't find any other name
    Lets try the command now

    $ # -i is used to ignore the case while searching
    $ # output contains only lines from second file not containing text for first file lines
    $ grep -v -i -f a.txt b.txt
    line doesnot contain any name
    Another line which doesnot contain any name
    I can't find any other name
    Lets try the command now
```

Comment: Might be nitpicking, but one can also combine the flags `grep -ivf ....` instead of `grep -i -v -f ....`
Although better sources exist, here is a link to the reminder of the flags: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of unix are you using? This will provide us with a better understanding of what is available to you from the command line. Currently what you have will not work, you're looking for the `diff` command which compares two files.

You can do the following for OS X 10.6 I have tested this at home.

```
diff -i -y FILE1 FILE2
```

`diff` compares the files `-i` will ignore the case if this does not matter so Hi and HI will still mean the same. Finally `-y` will output side by side the results If you want to out the information to a file you could do `diff -i -y FILE1 FILE2 >> /tmp/Results.txt`

Comment: It's on 10.6 Snow Leopard OS X server.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably better ways to do this ie. without grep but heres a solution which will work

```
grep -v -P "($(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/)|(/g' test1.txt))" test2.txt > answer.txt
```

To explain this:

`$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/)|(/g' test1.txt)` is an embedded sed command which outputs a string where each newline in test1.txt is replaced by `)|(` the output is then inserted into a perl style regex (`-P`) for grep to use, so that grep is searching test2.txt for the every line in text1.txt and returns only those in test2.txt which don't contain lines in test1.txt because of the `-v` param.